# How to implement custom plugin for Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Piecing together the code as much as I can from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide_sample_javascript and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins I have tried to make a demo that uses the "Echo" plugin.

**It doesn't work.**

In Safari's Web Inspector, I get the following when running on iPhone simulator:

```
[Log] Received Event: deviceready (index.js, line 47)
[Error] TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
            alert(echoValue == "echome"); // should alert true.
        })')
    receivedEvent (index.js, line 49)
    onDeviceReady (index.js, line 36)
    fire (cordova.js, line 750)
    (anonymous function) (cordova.js, line 223)
```

My best understanding of this plugin implementation is here: https://github.com/thegreatmichael/phonegap-echo-plugin-example and my best understanding of how to use it (i modified the basic, generated app as little as possible), is here: https://github.com/thegreatmichael/phonegap-app-uses-echo

**What should I do to have a working example of the echo plugin?**

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is because in plugin.xml you use `clobbers` but in your js you don't use `module.exports` to export your plugin object.

You have either to use `<runs/>` instead of `<clobbers target="echo" />` or modify your js to use module.exports (have a look at core cordova plugins for sample).

Comment: Maybe you're onto something, but when I change the js file to the following, the result in the webinspector and the resulting js put on the simulator are the same as before.

 var echo = function(str, callback) {
     cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
      callback('Nothing to echo.');
     }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);
 };

 module.exports = echo;

Comment: did you try leaving the js as is and using runs in plugin.xml?